# How to make a date distinct using EF6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having a hard time to make a date Distinct using Entity Framework 6, for example I have this in my database:

| user id | assigned date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-09 18:58:38.213 |
| 2 | 2020-12-09 20:59:38.213 |
| 1 | 2020-12-09 22:13:38.214 |
| 1 | 2020-12-10 18:27:38.213 |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 10:27:38.213 |

For user `1` I want it to return:

```
2020-12-09
2020-12-10
2021-01-05
```

This is what I have in `detalle.cs` model:

```
public DateTime? FechaAsignacionAlistado { get; set; }
```

This is what I have in my repository:

```
 public IList<DetalleSolicitud> GetDetallesPorUsuarioParaAsignacion(string userId)
    {
        return _context.DetalleSolicituds
            .Include(a => a.HistorialAsignacionAlistadors)
            .Include(s => s.Solicitudes.Pedido.ReservasProducs.Select(a => a.DetalleTalla.Producto))
            .Where(a => a.AlistadorId == userId).ToList();
    }
```

What I have tried but does not work ( I do not know what I am doing):

```
        public IList<DetalleSolicitud> GetDetallesPorUsuarioParaAsignacion(string userId)
    {
        return _context.DetalleSolicituds
            .Include(a => a.HistorialAsignacionAlistadors)
            .Include(s => s.Solicitudes.Pedido.ReservasProducs.Select(a => a.DetalleTalla.Producto))
            .GroupBy(a => a.FechaAsignacionAlistado).Distinct()
            .Where(a => a.AlistadorId == userId).ToList();
    }
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: There are a few questions here:1: Are you using the `.netcore` project? 2: Your `DateTime` data is different because they have different `hours, minutes and seconds`. Do you want to exclude data that is duplicated in `year, month, and day`?

Comment: 1.corrected, it is `asp.net mvc`. 2. I want to ignore `hours, minutes and seconds`. Anyway I got this by using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime((DateTime)a.FechaAsignacionAlistado)`

Comment: Your `FechaAsignacionAlistado ` must be nullable? Can I change it?

Comment: Yes it must be nullable.

Comment: What I can help you is:`_context.DetalleSolicituds.Include(a => a.HistorialAsignacionAlistadors).Include(s => s.Solicitudes.Pedido.ReservasProducs.Select(a => a.DetalleTalla.Producto)).Where(a => a.AlistadorId == userId).GroupBy(a => a.FechaAsignacionAlistado.ToShortDateString()).Distinct().ToList();`,but,it need you to delete the `?`....

Comment: I already answered this, I got this after 6 hours of struggling.

Comment: Glad you can solve it :).

Answer (score 0):

I got this by using a `.Groupby` and a `.Select` and worked perfectly.

```
    public IEnumerable<DetalleSolicitud> GetDetallesPorUsuarioParaAsignacion(string userId)
    {
        return _context.DetalleSolicituds
            .Include(a => a.HistorialAsignacionAlistadors)
            .Include(s => s.Solicitudes.Pedido.ReservasProducs.Select(a => a.DetalleTalla.Producto))
            .Where(a => a.AlistadorId == userId)
            .GroupBy(a => DbFunctions.TruncateTime((DateTime)a.FechaAsignacionAlistado))
            .ToList().Select(x => new DetalleSolicitud { FechaAsignacionAlistado = x.Key });
    }
```